# Extract address from unstructured table row with BeautifulSoup

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

I have a HTML document where I want to extract the address but I'm unable to. Here is the HTML document. It contains an address that is not enclosed with brackets, and a beginner like me is not able to extract it without it (e.g. with `find()` or similar).

```py
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Title</title>
</head>
<body>
<table class="novip">
    <tr class="novip">
        <td class="novip-portrait-picture"
            rowspan="5">
            <a class="novip" href="refer.html">URL</a>
        </td>
        <td class="novip-left">
            <a class="novip-firmen-name"
               href="refer.html"
               target="_top">
                John Doe
            </a>
        </td>
        <td class="novip-right"
            rowspan="2">
            <a class="novip" href="refer.html">URL</a>
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="novip">
        <td class="novip-left">
            <span class="novip-left-titel">
              Prof.
            </span>
            <span class="novip-left-fachbezeichnung">
              Professor for History
            </span>
            <br/>
            Rose Avenue 33, 4302843 A City
            <br/>
            Tel:&nbsp;<a>234 23 43244</a>
            &nbsp;&nbsp;
            <a class="novip-left-make_appointment-button-active">Booking</a>
            &nbsp;&nbsp;
        </td>
    </tr>

</table>

</body>
</html>
```

I would like to extract the address `Rose Avenue 33, 4302843 A City`.

Here is my attempt but I cannot narrow it down enough.

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup


r = requests.get(url)
r.encoding = 'utf8'
html_doc = r.text
soup = BeautifulSoup(html_doc, features='html5lib')
table = []

tables = soup.find_all("table", {"class": "novip"})

for table in tables:
    rows = table.findChildren('tr')
    
    address = rows[1].find('span', 'novip-left-fachbezeichnung').text
```

Comment: Mind sharing the URL?

Comment: [URL](https://www.doktor.ch/gynaekologen/gynaekologen_k_lu.html)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following code will approximate your attempt. It's based on bs4 (BeautifulSoup), pandas and requests:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup 
import pandas as pd

url =  'https://www.doktor.ch/gynaekologen/gynaekologen_k_lu.html'

r = requests.get(url)
soup = BeautifulSoup(r.text, 'html.parser')
dr_list = []
doctor_cards = soup.select('table.novip')
for card in doctor_cards:
    try:
        dr_name = card.select_one('a.novip-firmen-name').text.strip()
    except Exception as e:
        dr_name = 'No Name'
    try:
        dr_url = card.select_one('a').get('href')
    except Exception as e:
        dr_url = 'No Url'
    try:
        dr_title = card.select_one('span.novip-left-titel').text.strip()
    except Exception as e:
        dr_title = 'No title'
    try:
        dr_specialisation = card.select_one('span.novip-left-fachbezeichnung').text.strip()
    except Exception as e:
        dr_specialisation = 'No specialisation'
    try:
        dr_address_span = card.select_one('span.novip-left-adresszusatz')
        dr_address = dr_address_span.text.strip() + ' ' + dr_address_span.next_sibling.strip()
    except Exception as e:
        dr_address_span = 'No address'
        if len(card.select_one('span.novip-left-fachbezeichnung').next_sibling.strip()) > 5:
            dr_address = card.select_one('span.novip-left-fachbezeichnung').next_sibling.strip().replace('\n', ' ')
        elif len(card.select_one('span.novip-left-fachbezeichnung').next_sibling.next_sibling) > 5:
            dr_address = card.select_one('span.novip-left-fachbezeichnung').next_sibling.next_sibling.text.strip().replace('\n', ' ')
        else:
            dr_address = card.select_one('span.novip-left-fachbezeichnung').next_sibling.next_sibling.next_sibling.strip().replace('\n', ' ')

    dr_list.append((dr_name, dr_title, dr_specialisation, dr_address))
df = pd.DataFrame(dr_list, columns = ['Name', 'Title', 'Spec', 'Address'])
df.to_csv('swiss_docs.csv')
print(df.head())
```

This will save a csv file with dr details, looking like this:

```
Name    Title   Spec    Address
0   Wey Barbara Dr. med.    Fachärztin FMH für Gynäkologie u. Geburtshilfe  Hauptstrasse 12, 6033 Buchrain Tel: 041 444 30 80    Terminanfrage    Karte
1   Bohl Urs    Dr. med.    Facharzt FMH für Gynäkologie und Geburtshilfe   Seetalstrasse 11, 6020 Emmenbrücke
2   Füchsel Glenn   Dr. med.    Facharzt für Gynäkologie und Geburtshilfe   docstation Gesundheitszentrum Emmen Mooshüslistrasse 6, 6032 Emmen
3   Dal Pian Désirée    Dr. med.    Fachärztin FMH für Gynäkologie u. Geburtshilfe  Frauenpraxis Zero Plus Am Mattenhof 4a, 6010 Kriens
4   Gilke Ursula    Dr. med.    Fachärztin für Gynäkologie u. Geburtshilfe  Schachenstrasse 5, 6010 Kriens
5   Amann Stefanie  Dr. med.    Fachärztin FMH Gynäkologie u. Geburtshilfe  Frauenpraxis am See Alpenstrasse 1, 6004 Luzern
6   Ballabio Nadja  Dr. med.    Fachärztin FMH Gynäkologie und Geburtshilfe gyn-zentrum ag Haldenstrasse 11, 6006 Luzern
[...]
```

There are better, more elegant solutions out there. Have a look over the bs4 documentation, at https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/